# scrolling listview programmatically in Android

Tags: android-layout

How to scroll the list view programmatically so that I can jump fastly in a long list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try 'smoothScrollToPosition' method:

```
listview.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
```

Hope it helps!!